# Doubt of combinatorics in a question in algebraic geometry

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

I think the right number is $N=(r+1)(s+1)=rs+r+s+1$ because count $N$ is equivalent to find the number of ordered pairs $(i,j)$, where $0\le i\le r$ and $0\le j\le s$.

Thanks

Comment: No, that's the dimension as a vector space. You need to take minus $1$ if you want the *projective dimension*.

Comment: @LucaBressan haaa yes of course!!! thanks